# ¿Cómo ordenar datos de precios con sus respectivos productos?

Tags: c++

Tengo que hacer un programa que reciba los nombres y precios de "n" productos:

Si el precio es mayor a 500 aplicarle 10 %
Si es mayor a 1000 aplicarle 20%
Si es mayor a 2000 aplicarle 30%

Mostrar los nombres y precios ordenados con el método de selección después de aplicar el descuento a los productos relacionados.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Tienda{
    string P; //Precio
    float C; //Costo
}Base[100];

int A;
float final;

int main()
{
    cout<<"¿Cuantos productos registrara?"<<endl;
    cin>>A;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < A; i++){
        cout<<"----------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"Nombre del producto "<<i + 1<<endl;
        cin>>Base[i].P;
        cout<<"Precio del producto "<<i + 1<<endl;
        cin>>Base[i].C;
    }
cout<<"----------------------------"<<endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < A; i++){
    if(Base[i].C <= 500)
        {
        }
        else if(Base[i].C >= 501 && Base[i].C <= 1000)
        {
            Base[i].C = ((Base[i].C / 100) * 90);
        }
        
        else if(Base[i].C >= 1001 && Base[i].C <= 2000)
        {
            Base[i].C = ((Base[i].C / 100) * 80);
        }
        
        else if(Base[i].C >= 2001)
        {
            Base[i].C = ((Base[i].C / 100) * 70);
        }
    }
//---------------------Seleccion-------------------------
    int i, j,Aux, M;
    for(i = 0; i < A; i++){
        M = i;
        for(j = i + 1; j < A; j++){
            if(Base[j].C < Base[M].C){
                M = j;
            }
        }
        Aux = Base[i].C;
        Base[i].C = Base[M].C;
        Base[M].C = Aux;
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i < A; i++){
    cout<<"Precio final de "<<Base[i].P <<" es de: "<<Base[i].C<<endl;
    }
cout<<"----------------------------"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Lo que me imprime es esto:

[image: Lo que me imprime es esto:]

Pero yo necesito que lo imprima asi:

> Precio final de Jabon es de 468
> Precio final de Harina es de 816
> Precio final de Aceite es de 1414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso sucede porque solo estás ordenando los precios.

Necesitas mover la estructura completa. Con unas pequeñas modificaciones debería funcionar:

```
int i, j, M;
Tienda Aux;
for(i = 0; i < A; i++){
    M = i;
    for(j = i + 1; j < A; j++){
        if(Base[j].C < Base[M].C){
            M = j;
        }
    }
    Aux = Base[i];
    Base[i] = Base[M];
    Base[M] = Aux;
}
```

---

Una mejor de hacerlo es con [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) y [`sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

La ventaja sobre un arreglo es que puedes agregar todos los elementos que quieras.

En cuanto a `sort`, no tienes que implementar tu propio algoritmo. Solo tienes que pasar dos iteradores y la función que te permita determinar el orden. Así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Producto {
    string nombre;
    int precio;
};

int main() {
    vector<Producto> lista = { { "Queso", 500 }, { "Jamón", 200 }, { "Leche", 800 } };

    auto orden = [](const Producto &a, const Producto &b)
    {
        return a.precio > b.precio;
    };

    sort(lista.begin(), lista.end(), orden);
    
    for (const Producto &p : lista)
        cout << p.nombre << " - " << p.precio << '\n';
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##jZFdSsQwEMffe4phBbeFblkEQWztAcQHfVYf0nTsBtok5MOX0lN5BA9WJ82uuyi4TgiZ/Jj5z0zCtd50nM/zhZC89y1CJZR1BtlQJ0f2jtwpc0pY3ykj3I7CEm@F7ECyAa1mHMG6tkwSUvHcwaNRLZ0Khttps://tio.run/##ZZDPSsQwEMbvfYqhgttCtyyCILb2AcSDntVDmo7dQJsp@eNl2afyEXywOmm266IJIckv8818EzlN217Keb5SWg6@Q6gVWWdQjE3yyz5ROjKXRAw9GeX2HJZ4q3QPWoxoJyERrOuqJOEsXjp4NtTxTnBIgAfTJZjG1mC1IKUdTAaloio5sjDcR6F0lp80sXq9ZmpgUNYJeIADz/TFo6W0gNvdDo5FII9i/P7SjG7O6AnlHpncBQKhSkgsPPsi06HmZK/vmSRtLxxfiwL@ojZflNFYGAadNxpEGVuABtpy7Sa8r7UsGZctxssW@9BdEfsoUXfhsvjIo@iDDPxzM8F9VOTn4pK8g7qGqYwfGs4pbHkt8GSJz5s3veHfnecf).